# Draw sprite in draw loop

Tags: c++, sprite, textures, draw, sfml

Got a problem, when I am trying to draw a sprite in the draw loop it won't draw
In the constructor for this class I am setting the sprite.

Constructor I have:

```
texture.loadFromFile("img1.png");
sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

sprite and texture is in the header file

I did some experiments, and if I use `texture.loadFromFile();` in the draw loop it works.
But then I have to "reload" the picture 60 times per second.

```
void PlayerReceiver::draw(sf::RenderWindow & rw){
        //texture.loadFromFile("mario.png");

        //std::cout<<texture.getSize().y<<std::endl;

            rw.draw(sprite);

    }
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: There is a page for this: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.4/graphics-sprite.php My guess is that you destroy the object each time and therefore need to reload because the memory doesn't exist anymore

Comment: my palantir tells me that either `spirte` or `texture` are defined locally

Comment: the problem is that it wont draw becouse of the loop(but i cant see why it should'ent work), if i put this just strait on my main it works fine.

nice answers thank you guys ill try

Comment: Also note that you wouldn't be "reloading" the picture 60 times per seconds. Once loaded, any call to loadFromFile() with the same string as a parameter will return the image which is already loaded. Not saying this is optimal but just wanted to clear it up! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Got a problem, when I am trying to draw a sprite in the draw loop it
>   won't draw In the constructor for this class I am setting the sprite.

From what I understand from this question, you want to load a texture and sprite inside a constructor and it's not working when you try to draw it from your draw loop.

I have a program which loads textures in the constructor and it runs fine, so what I would imagine is wrong (and I'm not sure since I don't see but six lines of your program in the above post) is that the texture and sprite objects are not defined on a class level.

Here's my header file for a texture object I'm using:

```
class GraphPaper
{
    public:
        GraphPaper();
        ~GraphPaper();
        bool isObjectLoaded();
        sf::Sprite getSprite();

    private:
        void load(std::string filename);
        bool isLoaded;

        sf::Texture texture;
        sf::Sprite sprite;

        const std::string file = "images/Graph-Paper.png";
};
```

The texture and sprite objects are listed on a class-wide level as private members and are accessed through getter methods.

And here's the constructor for that class (altered a bit to better match what you were wanting done):

```
#include "GraphPaper.h"

GraphPaper::GraphPaper() //: isLoaded(false)
{
    if (texture.loadFromFile(file) == false)
        isLoaded = false;
    else
    {
        texture.setRepeated(true);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        isLoaded = true;
    }
    //load(file);
    assert(isObjectLoaded());
}
```

After this I simply draw my "GraphPaper" object.

```
mainWindow.draw(paper.getSprite());
```

I already have access to it because I defined a "GraphPaper" object called "paper" in my MainWindow header file.

```
#pragma once
#include "GraphPaper.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class MainWindow
{
    public:
         void close();
         void start();
         void moveCamera(sf::Event);

    private:
        bool leftMousePressed, rightMousePressed, isExiting;
        int r, g, b, mouseX, mouseY;

        GraphPaper paper;

        const sf::Color white = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);

        sf::RenderWindow mainWindow;
        sf::View view;
};
```

Assuming this is what you are wanting to do, then your problem is likely in the header file.  Any objects defined on a class level, once loaded, won't get destroyed until the class itself is destroyed.  Maybe you need to make sure you aren't destroying the reference to the class that the constructor is in.  For instance, if you create an instance of your class inside a loop, the moment that loop ends the class object will be destroyed.

Comment: Annnnd, jsut realized this was like 3 years old.  Oh well.

Comment: But it is a good answer, and might help someone else, so not a complete waste!

Answer (score 0):

Just a supposition: You have this in your construtor:

```
PlayerReceiver::PlayerReceiver()
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("img1.png");
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
}
```

This way the texture object is destroyed right after the constructor ends. Both the `sprite` and the `texture` must be members of the class, so that they don't get destroyed until the player itself is destroyed.

If this is not your problem, then please post more code.